# Restlet: How to get UTF-8 result from getText()?

Tags: utf-8, restlet

I use Restlet to implement a web service that processes POST requests, but I have problems with non-ASCII character encodings.

I added a filter that looks at the request before it is handled, and `request.getEntity().getCharacterSet()` returns `UTF-8`. But at any point, calling `getText()` on that entity returns `?????` for Korean strings in the input.

When I start the service locally on my machine, there's no problem; this happens only on the server. Although another web service running on that server, also using Restlet, can handle Korean strings properly -- the only difference is that it converts an incoming representation into a `Form` and then accesses the fields in that form (which maybe never calls `getText()`?).

Any ideas how I could find out where exactly the problem is?

Comment: On server side, by default, representations are instances of InputRepresentation class. When I have a look at the InputRepresentation#getText method, it creates an instance of InputStreamReader with the character set of the entity (if any). So for the moment, I have no explanation. Are you able to isolate the problem, for example by consuming the representation in the filter, of by writing the class of the request's entity (should be InputRepresentation)?

Comment: When converting the representation into a Form, the stream is URL decoded, which may explain the difference. Are you sending a web form?

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry for the long silence. The class of the request entity is indeed `InputRepresentation`. What is strange: `entity.getCharacterSet()` is `UTF-8`, but `entity.getText().getBytes("UTF-8")` throws an exception.

Comment: that's quite difficult to guess what happens. But I wonder if the stream is really UTF-8. I've just created an issue: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/1155 that will ease to solve the issue, and not pollute SOF comments/answers. Do you mind to switch to this ticket for solving the issue?